# Acquiring access token using AuthenticationContext of ADAL

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal, adal.js

I am using ADAL.js for acquiring token for Azure Resources.

```
<script src="https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/lib/1.0.15/js/adal.min.js"></script>
```

I have written the following code in order to do so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/lib/1.0.15/js/adal.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var endpoints = {
            "https://management.core.windows.net": "https://management.core.windows.net"
        };
        var config = {
            clientId: 'e333d3fe-a73a-4476-8121-8a57f9a972ca',
            endpoints: endpoints,
        };
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(config);
        authContext.handleWindowCallback();

        function login() {
            authContext.popUp = true;
            authContext.login();
           // authContext.handleWindowCallback();
            var user = authContext.getCachedUser();
            console.log(user);
        };

        function clickme() {
            var user = authContext.getCachedUser();
            console.log(user);

            authContext.acquireToken('https://management.core.windows.net', function (error, token) {
                console.log(error);
                console.log(token);
                ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                if (!!error) {
                    console.log(error.indexOf("interaction_required"));
                    authContext.acquireTokenPopup(
                        'https://management.core.windows.net/',
                        null,
                        null,
                        function (error, token, msg) {
                            console.log(error);
                            console.log(token);
                        }
                    )
                }
                +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
            });
        };

        function logout () {
            authContext.logout();
        };

    </script>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="clickme()" />
    <input id="Button3" type="button" value="login" onclick="login()" />
    <input id="Button2" type="button" value="logout" onclick="logout()" />

    // These are the text-boxes whose value I want to retain.
    First name:<br>
    <input id=fname" type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
    <br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input id="lname" type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
</body>
</html>
```

There are two issues with the above code:

1. When I call authContext.acquireToken(): The following error came : **AADSTS50079: The user is required to use multi-factor authentication.** 
   authContext.login() function only asks for credentials once and didn't ask for multi factor authentication. How can I handle this ?
2. When we click on logout, the value for the fname textbox and lname textbox is lost as page got refreshed. How can I avoid the reload of the page?
3. I have updated the code according to the answer, But got the following error message: **Popup Window is null. This can happen if you are using IE**. Have I done anything wrong here?? I am using chrome. *The following issue is coming as the pop-up was blocked in the chrome. After allowing the pop-up, the code is working fine.*

Comment: For the logout, the request has to be made to the AAD endpoint which will handle the clearing of the appropriate session cookies. I don't think the page refresh can be avoided unless there is a way to avoid it by making the request from a hidden iframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error ***AADSTS50079: The user is required to use multi-factor authentication*** means that particular end user must perform or enroll in multi-factor auth in order to get an access token.  `acquireToken()` is a silent request, so it's unable to show the MFA UI to the end user.  Calling `login()` doesn't resolve this because you're not requesting access to anything in a login call.

The workaround is to catch this error:

`if (error.indexOf("interaction_required") !== -1)`

Then, your app can use either [`acquireTokenPopup()`](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/adal.js#L585) or [`acquireTokenRedirect()`](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/adal.js#L634) which are interactive requests on the same resource.  This will then prompt your end user to fulfill the MFA request and you'll get your access token.

Comment: I have tried this:  `authContext.acquireToken('https://management.core.windows.net/', function (error, token) {
        console.log(error.indexOf("interaction_required"));
}`. In the log -1 got printed.

Comment: I have updated the code and the question in accordance to your answer. Please take a look into this.

Comment: The  error message: **Popup Window is null. This can happen if you are using IE**:  is coming as the popup was blocked on the chrome for that particular site "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2......."

Comment: Still error.indexOf("interaction_required") is -1 only for me.

Comment: @AkashAgarwal can you open up a browser debugger and see what `error` says with this case?  It's possible there's an additional error you may need to catch.